# "Is X and Y the exact same thing?" or "Are X and Y the exact same things?"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Which one is more correct grammatically speaking in English?

> a)  Is X and Y the exact same thing?
>   b)  Are X and Y the exact same things?
>   c)  Are X and Y the exact same thing?

Please state your answer for : 1) BrE and 2) AmE.

And the sources. Please :)

Also how common is it for Native English People to not follow the correct grammar pattern for this?

How often do you hear Native English speaker mistakenly saying using option a or b (whichever one is the incorrect one, which I don't know yet), even though it is incorrect?

NOTE there are two objects being mentioned here X and Y. Regardless whether they are countable or uncountable things. So there are two things, no more and no less than that.

Answer (score 4):

In formal American English, the correct version of the question is:

> c) Are X and Y the exact same thing?

The subject and verb are plural, because we start by discussing two different concepts.

The complement is singular -- one hypothetical concept that the subjects might be identical to.

An equally correct question is:

> d) Are X and Y two different things?

In this question, the complement is plural.

Answer (score 2):

South East Asian English (SEA-E) aka the one spoken with lots of lah suffixes... and Based upon the English spoken by majority of the Commonwealth countries.
Personally I lean towards

> a) Is X and Y the same thing?

as it refers to the question whether x and y are equal. A singular item.

However it is taught in school that both X and Y are already 2 items; therefore the subjects need to be referred in a plural.
Furthermore the result is singular item. Hence

> C) Are X and Y the same thing?

Comment: Thank you for your post.  We welcome new perspectives on this site.  I made a few minor spelling and formatting corrections.  If you don't like them, you can revert them by clicking on the "edited __ mins ago" link, and then clicking a "rollback" link.  If you want me to edit the grammar as well, please let me know in a follow-up comment.